# Why adding a file /etc/crontabs/www-data in dockerfile will make the cron job for www-data when run the container (alpine based)

Tags: docker, cron, alpine-linux

I know the proper way to add cron job for the user www-data is to run `crontab -u www-data -e`

So to do that in dockerfile I should add a line like `RUN crontab -u www-data /some_where/crontab.conf`

But I found if I do this, it works too (the docker image is based on alpine3.7).

```
ADD /some_where/crontab /etc/crontabs/www-data
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/crontabs/www-data
```

But I can't find the document explaining why it works. So why does it work and does this mean if I add another file called www to /etc/crontabs it will make a cronjob for www (assume I have www user) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this](http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html):

> Multiuser cron
>
> As Unix is a multiuser OS, some of the apps have to be able to support 
>   multiple users, cron is one of these. Each user can have their own crontab
>   file, which can be created/edited/removed by the command crontab. This
>   command creates an individual crontab file and although this is a text file,
>   as the /etc/crontab is, it shouldn't be edited directly. The crontab file is
>   often stored in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/<user>` (Unix/Slackware/*BSD), 
>   `/var/spool/cron/<user>` (RedHat) or `/var/cron/tabs/<user>` (SuSE), 
>   but might be kept elsewhere depending on what Un*x flavor you're running.

And in alpine, it also in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs`, just `/var/spool/cron/crontabs` is a symbol link of `/etc/crontabs`, so you can also put it in `/etc/crontabs`:

```
/etc/crontabs # ls -alh  /var/spool/cron/crontabs
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root          13 Jun 19 17:14 /var/spool/cron/crontabs -> /etc/crontabs
```

Comment: But why the file name  is used for a specific user. I can't find document for that.

Comment: `The crontab file is often stored in /var/spool/cron/crontabs/<user> (Unix/Slackware/BSD)` this not enough?

Comment: Oh yes it should be enough :$